# I need to replace all instances of [IMG] in a string using PHP

Tags: php

I've tried:

```
$input = str_replace('[IMG]',"",$input,$rplc);
```

with no success.

I've also tried escaping and double-escaping [IMG] by doing '[IMG]' and '\[IMG\]', neither worked. It doesn't throw any errors, but it doesn't actually replace anything either.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Please post `$input` and `$rplc` values, what i tried at my end is working fine.

Comment: I also tried your code it working fine. please post your `$input` and `$rplc` value

Comment: You only need to escape a single quote between single quotes (with a backslash, and thus you need to escape the backslash as well), nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
$input = preg_replace("/(\\[IMG\\])/", $replacement, $input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this example, to implement within your code..

```
 $search = "[IMG]";
 $replace = "";
 $string = "Hello [IMG] Approxx? How[IMG] are [IMG]You?";
 $input = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
 echo $input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> ```
>     preg_replace("@\[img\]@","",$input);
> ```

And the same result can also be achived by using

**str_replace()**

> ```
>   str_replace("[img]",'',$input);
> ```